# How to show a html hidden div after clicking a submit button in another php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have this div in `seosystem/index.php`

```
<div class="class" id="ScoreResult" style="display:none;">

  <div class="row border border-5 " style="background:whitesmoke;">

    <div class=" col toast w-20  z-depth-5 shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded show w-100">
      <div class="toast-header">
        <strong class="me-auto">Description</strong>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast"></button> !-->
      </div>
      <div class="toast-body ">
        <div class="progress" style="height:20px; width:200px;">
          <div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width:33.33%"></div>
          <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" style="width:33.33%"> </div>
          <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" style="width:33.33%"> </div>
        </div>
        <p>10/10</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm   border border-5 col-xxl mx-auto">
      <h4><?php echo "Title: " . $title; ?></h4>
      <?php echo "<iframe style=\"background-color:whitesmoke;\" position=\"center\"allow=\"accelerometer\"; gyroscope;  width=\"100%\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$ytcode\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>";
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and i have this function in `seosystem/controller/youtubedata.php` i tried using Js it didn't work
so i want when the user submit the button it shows the div to display the data

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET" && isset($_GET['url']) && isset($_GET['submit'])){

    /*  echo  "</br >" ; 
    echo   $input_Url_data   .  "Button clicked" ;  */    
    $id_position = strstr($input_Url_data,"=");
    $id_position = trim($id_position, "=" );
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
 'showtable(){
    document.getElementById(<?php echo "ScoreResult" ;?>).style.display = "block";

 }',
 '</script>' ; 

}
```

This the form of the input and the button i'm not sure should i make the action `index.php` or `seosystem/controller/youtubedata.php`

```
 <form class="d-flex justify-content-center " method="GET" action="index.php">
      <div class="input-group ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" placeholder="Enter Youtube Video URL" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
        <input class="btn" value="Analyze" name="submit" type="submit" id="button-addon1"></input>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: In JS you define a function, but you don't run it.

Comment: I thought it will be invoked automatically I edited it and still not working
`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET" && isset($_GET['url']) && isset($_GET['submit'])){

        /*  echo  "</br >" ; 
        echo   $input_Url_data   .  "Button clicked" ;  */    
        $id_position = strstr($input_Url_data,"=");
        $id_position = trim($id_position, "=" );
        echo '<script> showtable(); </script>';
    }`

Comment: and added this part in the first in `seosystem/controller/youtubedata.php`

`<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function showtable()
   {
    
    document.getElementById( "ScoreResult").style.display = "block";

       
    }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="..\bootstrap\scriptname.js"></script>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: I executed js sample and it works, do you think the function can't read the div's id because it's from another file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two invalid variables there.. **TITLE** & **YTCODE**. Well I don't know how you got those.

But to display the DIV Only when response is valid here's the code;

```
youtube.php
```

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET" && isset($_GET['url']) && isset($_GET['submit'])){

/*  echo  "</br >" ; 
echo   $input_Url_data   .  "Button clicked" ;  */    
$id_position = strstr($input_Url_data,"=");
$id_position = trim($id_position, "=" );
$verified_success = "yes"; // This is the conditional variable.
/* echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
'showtable(){
document.getElementById(<?php echo "ScoreResult" ;?>).style.display = "block";

}',
'</script>' ;  */

}
```

```
index.php
```

```
<?php

// Stop Irrelevant Warning Signs From Showing such as invalid variables
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
include("youtube.php");
?>

<?php
                  if ($verified_success == NULL) {
                    ?>
<form class="d-flex justify-content-center " method="GET" action="">
      <div class="input-group ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" placeholder="Enter Youtube Video URL" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
        <input class="btn" value="Analyze" name="submit" type="submit" id="button-addon1"></input>
      </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>


<?php
    if ($verified_success != NULL) {
?>

<div class="class" id="ScoreResult">

  <div class="row border border-5 " style="background:whitesmoke;">

    <div class=" col toast w-20  z-depth-5 shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded show w-100">
      <div class="toast-header">
        <strong class="me-auto">Description</strong>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast"></button> !-->
      </div>
      <div class="toast-body ">
        <div class="progress" style="height:20px; width:200px;">
          <div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width:33.33%"></div>
          <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" style="width:33.33%"> </div>
          <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" style="width:33.33%"> </div>
        </div>
        <p>10/10</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm   border border-5 col-xxl mx-auto">
      <h4><?php echo "Title: " . $title; ?></h4>
      <?php echo "<iframe style=\"background-color:whitesmoke;\" position=\"center\"allow=\"accelerometer\"; gyroscope;  width=\"100%\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$ytcode\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>";
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks it solved, the YTCODE variable is for saving youtube video id and use it for `<iframe>`